# the alamofire isn't doing a proper connection to the api

Tags: swift, alamofire

i am trying to get a response that contain json from openweathermap api,
but from the debugger it seems that when he get to the code block of alamofire its just skips it

here is the block of code that i am using for this task

```
func printJson(){

    Alamofire.request("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?appid=6ad1f143546b8c6d761ecbda6a34a005&q=yavne", method: .get).responseJSON { response in
        if response.data != nil {
            var json : JSON
            do{
                json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                print(json)
        }catch{}
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this helper class to make API calls.

```
class NetworkHandler {

    static let shared = NetworkHandler()

    func sendRequest(withUrl url:String,andBody body:[String:Any]? = [:],
                         completionHandler: @escaping ((_ status: Bool,_ response:Any) -> Void)) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: body,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
                response in

                guard response.response?.statusCode == 200 else{
                    completionHandler(false,"Service Temporarily Unavailable.\nPlease check your internet connection or  contact your Service provider.")
                    return
                }
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    completionHandler(true,response.value!)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    completionHandler(false,error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This dispatch to a global queue is rather pointless. You shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: can you please tell what should I use either?